# Python - error in mocking method that calls psutil.process_iter

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock, psutil

I have a method (below), in a module `utils.py` that uses `psutil.process_iter` to find and generate process info. dicts (`psutil.Process.as_dict`) based on the name of a given process. If the process name doesn't exist, or process errors are encountered, nothing is generated. The module contains of course the import of `psutil`.

```
def get_processes_by_name(process_name):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            pinfo = proc.as_dict()

            if process_name == pinfo['name']:
                yield pinfo
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
```

I am trying to write a number of unit tests for this method, for different scenarios, using `unittest.mock`. The test cases are in a test module `test_utils.py`. The following is an example.

```
    def test__process_instances_by_name__one_running_proc_matches_given_proc_name__one_proc_instance_generated(self):
        mock_proc1 = MagicMock()
        mock_proc1.as_dict = MagicMock(return_value={'name': 'some_other_proc_name'})

        mock_proc2 = MagicMock()
        mock_proc2.as_dict = MagicMock(side_effect=psutil.AccessDenied(2))

        mock_proc3 = MagicMock()
        mock_proc3.as_dict = MagicMock(return_value={'name': 'test_proc_name', 'exe': 'test/proc/exec/path', 'pid': 3})

        with patch('utils.psutil.process_iter', MagicMock()) as mock_process_iter:
            mock_process_iter.iter.return_value = iter([mock_proc1, mock_proc2, mock_proc3])

            received_process_instances = list(get_processes_by_name('test_proc_name'))

            self.assertEqual(received_process_instances, [mock_proc3])
```

Note that I am not patching `psutil.process_iter` directly, but its import in the target module `utils.py` in which the target method is defined. I think is the correct approach.

In this test case here I create three mock processes: the first (`mock_proc1`) generates a process error (`psutil.AccessDenied`) when `as_dict` is called, the second (`mock_proc2`) has a different name to the one I'm looking for, but the last one (`mock_proc3`) represents a valid process with the required name `test_proc_name`. The idea is that when `get_processes_by_name` is called with `test_proc_name` the method should generate `mock_proc3` only. As `get_processes_by_name` is a generator (following `psutil.process_iter`) I have followed the `unittest` docs on [how to mock generating methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mocking-a-generator-method).

Unfortunately, this test case is failing - the target method is not generating anything so the assertion fails (`ipdb` output below).

```
ipdb> 
> /path/to/tests/test_utils.py(352)test__get_processes_by_name__one_running_proc_matches_given_proc_name__one_proc_instance_generated()
    351 
--> 352             self.assertEqual(received_process_instances, [mock_proc3])
    353 

ipdb> 
AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != [<MagicMock id='4660019536'>]

Second list contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 0:
<MagicMock id='4660019536'>
```

I have tried to debug the target method using `ipdb` (putting a breakpoint at the top of the target method), and I can see the following output.

```
> /path/to/utils.py(183)get_processes_by_name()
    182     import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
--> 183     for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    184         try:

ipdb> 
ipdb> n
StopIteration
> /path/to/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py(203)_multicall()
    202             try:
--> 203                 gen.send(outcome)
    204                 _raise_wrapfail(gen, "has second yield")

ipdb> 
    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]
```

I don't know what is going on here. Is it complaining about the multiple yields in `psutil.process_iter`, or is there an error in the mocking. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this by changing the function and mocking.